# How to apply code of certain script to another?

Tags: unity, c#, collision-detection

I have a code in my "OnCollider" script to respawn whenever the player dies and has taken an object containing tag 'Respawn'.
1st script: OnCollider ;

```
     using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;

    public class OnColllider : MonoBehaviour {
        public GameObject Doorfinder;
        public GameObject Door2;
        public Transform Camera;
        public Transform target;
        public GameObject Coin;
        public bool collided;
        public GameObject Playee;
        public GameObject currentRespawn;
        void Start(){ 
            Door2 = GameObject.Find ("Door0.2");
            Playee = GameObject.Find ("Player");
        }
        public void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision){


            if (collision.gameObject.name == 

"scroll") {
            Destroy (collision.gameObject);
            Destroy (Doorfinder);
        } 
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Fire" ) {
            Playee.SetActive (false);
        }


        if (collision.gameObject.name == "PathFinder") {
            Destroy (collision.gameObject);
            Destroy (Door2);
        }

        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Coin") {
            Destroy (collision.gameObject);
        }

        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "subVillains") {
            Playee.SetActive (false);
        }
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Bramble") {

            Playee.SetActive (false);
        }

        Respawnable (collision);
    }
    public void Respawnable (Collision2D collision){
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Respawn") {
            collided = true;
            collision.gameObject.SetActive (false);

        }
        if (collided = true && Playee.activeInHierarchy == false) {
            transform.position = currentRespawn.transform.position;
            Playee.SetActive (true);
            collided = false;
        }
        if (currentRespawn.activeInHierarchy == false && collision.gameObject.tag == "Respawn") {
            currentRespawn = collision.gameObject;

        }

    }

}
```

2nd Script: Enemy;

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MaxyMory: MonoBehaviour {
    public Vector2 origin;
    public float distance;
    public int layerMask;
    public float sider;
    public Vector2 secondorigin;
    public float bringer;
    public float lesngther;
    public GameObject destroy;
    public Vector2 origination;
    public float middle;
    public float lengther;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        origin = new Vector2 (transform.position.x + bringer, transform.position.y + sider);
        origination = new Vector2 (transform.position.x + bringer, transform.position.y + middle);
        secondorigin = new Vector2 (transform.position.x + bringer, transform.position.y + lengther);   
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    public void Update(GameObject Playee){
        Debug.DrawRay (origin, Vector2.right*distance,  Color.red);
        Debug.DrawRay (secondorigin, Vector2.right * distance, Color.cyan);
        Debug.DrawRay (origination, Vector2.right * (distance + 30f), Color.gray);
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast (origin, Vector2.right, distance);
        RaycastHit2D anotherhit = Physics2D.Raycast (secondorigin, Vector2.right, distance);
        RaycastHit2D checker = Physics2D.Raycast (origination, Vector2.right, distance + 2f);
        if (hit.collider.tag == "Player" || anotherhit.collider.tag == "Player") {
            Playee.SetActive (false);
        }

    }

}
```

OnCollider is attached to the player while the enemy script is attached to the enemy itself.

Comment: What platform are you using? This looks like XNA/Monogame.

Comment: This platform is unity.

Comment: It looks like you might be trying to use that second `if` to say "from now on, anytime the player gets deactivated, do the following..." but that's not how an `if` statement works in C#. It just tests the condition *now*, in the current collision event, and then forgets about this code until the next time something fires the collision handler again. You might want to use an [OnDisable message](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnDisable.html) instead?

Comment: In the second code, I wanted to check if the player has hit (something ) or not? If it has hit, it deactivates the player and after the player is deactivated, I want the rest to be handle by another script 'OnCollider'. But, the problem is that, I cannot call the script in my enemy script because it has parameters (Collision2D collision) @DMGregory

Comment: Then pull the meat you want to act on into another method that you can call, as illustrated below.

Comment: @DMGregory Look at my whole code and please tell me what adjustments should I make according to the second answer because I just want these two script to connect and not change the whole script.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you might want something more like a Respawnable component that exposes a respawning method that other scripts can call when they want to kill/respawn the player avatar:

```
public class Respawnable : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject currentRespawnPoint;
    bool hasUnusedRespawnPoint;

    public bool TryRespawn() {
        if (hasUnusedRespawnPoint == false) {
            gameObject.SetActive(false);
            return false;
        }

        transform.position = currentRespawnPoint.transform.position;
        gameObject.SetActive(true);
        hasUnusedRespawnPoint = false;

        return true;
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) {
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Respawn") == false)
            return;

        collision.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        hasUnusedRespawnPoint = true;

        // It's unclear whether you need this.
        // Generally, if the game object is disabled,
        // its collision methods won't even fire.
        // I've kept it to match your existing script.
        if(gameObject.activeInHierarchy == false)
            TryRespawn();

        currentRespawnPoint = collision.gameObject;
    }

}
```

Your enemy script can then invoke just the respawn logic when it needs to, by calling the public`TryRespawn` method directly :

```
var respawnable = playerObject.GetComponent<Respawnable>();
respawnable.TryRespawn();
```

Comment: I just want the function having parameters to be called in another script. What's the need in changing the code?

Comment: Your current code does not achieve the desired effect. This code does achieve the desired effect. That is the need for changing the code.

Answer (score 0):

The original answer is a good answer and works but to me it sounds like you just want to fully understand calling some logic in script2 from script1.

one way to handle that without one script being a 'singleton' or using 'static' is to simply just add the reference to the other script.

```
public class Script1 : MonoBehaviour
{
    //reference script2
    //make it public and add the script or set the reference with code in awake or start
   //in your case can even set it in the collision itself (not recommended).

    Script2 otherScript;

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        /// Your stuff on script 1

        //call something you want handled in script2
        otherScript.OtherStuffOnScript2();
    }

}


public class Script2 : MonoBehaviour
{

    public void OtherStuffOnScript2()
    {
        //Script 2 stuff
    }
}
```

To better understand doing the same as above with a parameter or even multiple parameters ie.(GameObject go, Vector3 position, ect..)

```
public class Script1 : MonoBehaviour
{
    //reference script2
    //make it public and add the script or set the reference with code in awake or start.
    Script2 otherScript;

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        /// Your stuff on script 1

        //call something you want handled in script2
        //passing the gameobject to script 2 with the parameter.
        otherScript.OtherStuffOnScript2(gameObject);
    }

}


public class Script2 : MonoBehaviour
{

    public void OtherStuffOnScript2(GameObject go)
    {
        //Script 2 stuff
        //go is the GameObject you sent with call from script1
    }
}
```

Comment: I think out of all you have got my answer. But, can you explain it all in detail. What is the gameobject that we pass in .otherStuffOnScript2 supposed to be ? How is it going to call the logic in Script2 ? I want it because when I tried the last code you wrote exactly, it didn't do anything rather it stopped the code of my enemy (Script2). How are we going to use that go here?

Comment: the gameobject passing would be the gameobject that the script1 was attached to and the other stuff in script2 would be what you wanted to run. Could be a respawn call or anything you would like. for the last issue make sure the script is referenced. if you use 'public Script2 otherScript' you can just drag it in the slot and test it out. otherwise make sure to reference the other script in start or awake

Comment: I have written my whole script. Please, tell me what changes  I should make because the code you wrote just isn't working out!